# Maven dependency doesn't get downloaded

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I have a Maven Scala project and in the pom.xml I have this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have this project in Eclipse but for some reason Eclipse keeps telling me that this jar file doesn't exist and it is now shown under Maven dependency section. This is not the case for other dependencies. what is wrong with this one?

Comment: This version was released only a month ago, so your corporate repo may not contain this artifact. Check your corporate repo. If you don't use a corporate repo, show us the repo URLs you've configured in your `settings.xml` and `pom.xml`.

Comment: - I assume that you using company provided repository so:
1) Check you corporate maven repo. Search for artifact 
2) If you don't have one - you need to get access to repo in external wold. See  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html  for a reference